# How to prompt user to specify a file location in Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin, filepath

I have feature that exports and generates csv using opencsv in vaadin 7. The problem I have is how to get a file location to save a file on users local machine.

Below is a line that needs a path to where to save a generated file.

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("H:\\dummy\\export"+timestamp+".csv"));
```

Instead of having a static file path, I need to prompt the user for where to save a file, as well as how the user wants to name a file.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have no chance to influence the location of a file that a user downloads.

Here you can find a sample how to create a download with vaadin: 
[Letting The User Download A File](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/LettingTheUserDownloadAFile.html)

Note: The Vaadin7 Link broke, this is for Vaadin8 but still helpful.